# My blog name refer to different domain in SERP

Tags: seo

When I typed `site:example.com` in Google's search box, it's sometime displaying a different title and meta description (of other website) and sometime same as my blog, but the thing puzzling me is the site URL is redirecting me to `somesite.com` and not my blog.

However when I type only brand name `example` in the search box and click on the first result, it's redirecting me to different site.

Note: This issue is not limited to Google. It also for all major search engines. Also this is regarding my home page only, all other post pages are working well.

I don't know what's going on here. Anyone else have the same issue? How do I fix this?

UPDATE: http://aw-snap.info/file-viewer/?tgt=http%3A%2F%2Fwebblogsforyou.com&ref_sel=Google&ua_sel=ff&fs=1

Comment: Why do you think this is a WordPress issue? What do the Google webmaster tools say?

Comment: sorry I forgot to add the research link. Question Updated with link. And here is what other SEO webmasters said: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/81766/google-shows-different-results-for-my-brandname-in-their-serp?noredirect=1#comment97200_81766